# set up a custom domain name on Google App engine to use with SSL

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl

I'm trying to set up a custom domain name on Google App engine to use with SSL.

I have a paid Google Apps account, the domain name is an Alias of my primary domain

I managed to set up the custom name via **https://console.developers.google.com/project - > My project -> App engine -> Settings -> Custom domains**

It works pretty well without `https`. But with `https` I have an error.

When I try **https://appengine.google.com/ -> My project -> Application Settings -> Add Domain**, I can select my domain name in the input box but when I click on "Add domain"

Google Ask to choose an account, I select my Google Apps account and I have this error:
*You are trying to access Google Admin of example.com but you do not have a valid logged in account for it.*

Sign into one of the existing accounts for example.com
This is weird because the domain name is an Alias as required by Google here: developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain

I tried to do all this procedure in a clean browser with only the Google Apps account logged and I have the same issue.

Is it a limitation from Google or so?

Comment: "It works pretty well without https. But with https I have an error." - what is the error?

Comment: the error is a standard "SSL connection error"

Comment: What does `openssl s_client -connect -tls1 server:443 -servername server` return?

Comment: as far as I know I can't launch that command on App engine

Comment: I found the solution. When you add a domain you have to add the **Primary domain**. And only after you can select an alias domain